# Android : intercept Javascript code with arguments to call java methods

Tags: javascript, android, html

i can't figure out how getting all javascript methods and their parameters from webview inside a fragment and calling specific java methods for each one;

In my fragment i have an html code like this :

```
String str="<div class=\"comment-page\" onclick=\"addComment(16802)\" style=\"margin-bottom:30px;background:none no-repeat right center #F4ECE1; padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;border-top:3px solid #401B01; padding-left:5px; font-size:16px;\">add comment <img src=\"add.png\"/></div>
content.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.mysite.com/",str, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

when i click on "add comment" i would like to show new activity or new fragment that contains a webview with input fields and "send" button which also has a javascript method .

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737439/android-callbacks-with-webview-component

Comment: that for links presents in webview,not for javascript code

Comment: you can have javascript code redirect to another url, I didn't try but it might catch the callback

Comment: there is "addComment" function in js code portion with a parameter ,i would like to open new activity with an intent and put in this paramter.i hope that you understand me