# How to change Activity when url has changed in webview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have this code:

```
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.org/login")
```

I want to change activity when login complete. How can i do it in Kotlin?

Comment: Hi! Check the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312499/android-detect-webview-url-change.

Comment: Witch url do you want to change when loaded?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder, Thanks!

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737439/android-callbacks-with-webview-component/3738290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        override fun doUpdateVisitedHistory(view: WebView, url: String, isReload: Boolean) {
            if (myWebView.url != "https://www.kryptex.org/login"){
                val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```